# Invalid Column name but still working

Tags: sql-server-2012

When I connect to the server name using it's name SQL is showing red lines under the code and stating things like column invalid or object invalid. But the code stills runs. When I connect to the server using it's IP I do not get the red lines and the code also runs.

Can I trust the data when using the name? Also why is it doing this?

I am using SSMS 2012 to access a brand new 2012 server.

Comment: I would disagree with you saying it was an invalid column. If intellisense showing it as an invalid column or object then it's the problem with the intellisense not the SQL server. If the column is invalid you will get an error [Invalid column name '<Your_ColumnName>'] when you execute the query. The SSMS intellisense is not that great [compared to Visual Studio] as far as I know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you make the column since the last time you refreshed your local intellisense cache?  Try doing that and seeing if it shows as valid.

Edit -> Intellisense -> Refresh Local Cache and then ctrl + Shift + R

Give that a shot and see if it works for you.

Comment: Intrigue with the same phenomena and worry about corruption of SSMS, but it was just Intellisense. Many thanks,