# FK constraint at SaveChange()

Tags: c#, entity-framework, code-first

Learning [EF6 code-first](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/code-first-conventions.aspx). By foreign key convention, I would have **StandardId** as Student Table's FK instead of the ugly **Standards_StandardId**. Even though I follow the tutorial word-to-word, I got exception while updating the database at `ctx.SaveChanges()`.

I thought some convention of my Entity Framework is not working properly. So I tried DataAnnotation `[ForeignKey("StandardId")]` on `public Standard Part { get; set; }` to override the FK. But still I receive the exact same error!

Is my SQL Server "not talking with" my Entity Framework, or something is corrupted? Below are all the codes and error messages in detail:

**Entity Model**

```
public class Student {
    public Student() { }
    public int StudentID { get; set; }
    public string StudentName { get; set; }

    //Foreign key for Standard
    public int StandardId { get; set; } <- StandardId, not Standard_StandardId
    public Standard Standard { get; set; } }

public class Standard {
    public Standard() { }
    public int StandardId { get; set; }
    public string StandardName { get; set; } 
    public ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; } }
```

**DbContext and DbSet**

```
namespace EF_Code_First_Tutorials {
    public class SchoolContext: DbContext {
        public SchoolContext(): base() { }
        public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Standard> Standards { get; set; } } }
```

**Main**

```
class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        using (var ctx = new SchoolContext()) {
            Student stud = new Student() { StudentName = "New Student" };  
            ctx.Students.Add(stud);
            ctx.SaveChanges(); } } } <-- ERROR!
```

**In Visual Studio**

> An exception of type
>   'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException' occurred in
>   EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code

**In InnerException**

> {"The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   \"FK_dbo.Students_dbo.Standards_StandardId\". The conflict occurred in
>   database \"EF_Code_First_Tutorials.SchoolContext\", table
>   \"dbo.Standards\", column 'StandardId'.\r\nThe statement has been
>   terminated."}

Comment: if i remove `public int StandardId { get; set; }` and use default `Standards_StandardId`, then it works. But I prefer to have the same name of FK as its related Primary Key (StandardId).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your relationship between `Student` and `Standard` is **not optional**, it is required. It means, that when you save a `Student`, it has to have `StandardId` assigned to an existing `Standard` record's id.

**EDIT**:

So, your program should include creation of the `Standard` object:

```
class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        using (var ctx = new SchoolContext()) {
            Student stud = new Student() { StudentName = "New Student" };  
            ctx.Students.Add(stud);
            Standard stan = new Standard { StandardId = 524 };
            stud.StantardId = stan.StandardId;
            ctx.Standards.Add(stan);
            ctx.SaveChanges(); } } }
```

If you want to make the relationship optional, the `Student` should have

`public int? StandardId { get; set; }`

Instead of:

`public int StandardId { get; set; }`

Comment: It works now. Except when I browse the rows in SSMS, I see SSMS red-underlined `StandardId` when move-hover, it says `Invalid column name 'StandardId'`. My code all seems to work without error, just wonder why SSMS underlined it as invalid in SQL script window.

Comment: Do your queries on DB still execute? If yes, then just ignore the error for now, SSMS sometimes freak out like that. I do not know the reason, so you have to search a bit more to solve this issue with SSMS.

Comment: Thank you. The queries execute just fine in DB. SSMS just underlines it in red. I will research into it or post it as a new question.

Comment: Turns out that the mysterious underline was due to Intellisense caching. See [SO: Invalid column but still working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28310089/invalid-column-name-but-still-working)